# Get form hidden variables to a function

Tags: php, javascript, html

I know that function will need to call out by using onclick or any events. But is it possible to get a hidden value without user handling.

Sample Form:

```
 $ID = 3;
 $Report1 = "Test1.docx";
 <form id = "Test" action="Nextpage.php">
 //Not sure how to call out my function over here...
 <input type="hidden" id="ID" name="ID" value="<?php echo $ID ?>"/> 
 <input type="hidden" id="ReportPath" name="ReportPath" value="<?php echo $ReportPath ?>"/> 
 //Once user click, function of RemoveDoc() will handle it.
 <input type="submit" id="Remove" name="<?php echo $Report1?>" value="Remove" title="Remove report1" onclick="return RemoveDoc(this.name, this.getAttribute('Report1'));" />
```

My function:

```
 function Remove(ID, ReportPath, Report1)
 {
xmlhttp1=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp1.open("GET","functions/call.php?ID="+ID+"&ReportPath="+ReportPath+"&Report1="+Report1,true);
xmlhttp1.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
    if (xmlhttp1.readyState==4 && xmlhttp1.status==200)
     {
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=           xmlhttp1.responseText;
     }
 }
xmlhttp1.send();
    return false;
 }
```

So how can i pass in the hidden value of the input into my function Remove(ID,ReportPath...) since it's now hidden and no action taken. Kindly advise.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. However, you can get/set values just like you do on non hidden elements: document.getElementById("ID").value Can you explain? Do you want to pass in the value as a parameter or will the function retrieve a value?

Comment: Want to pass out my variable as a parameter in the function so that I can call out in my call.php to get these values. Got any idea I can get these hidden values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just get

```
var id = document.getElementById('ID').value;
var reportpath  = document.getElementById('ReportPath').value;
var report1  = document.getElementById('Report1').value;
```

Call the function:

```
Remove(id, reportpath, report1);
```

To make things easier for you. You can use jquery. Just include it in your page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="Test" action="Nextpage.php">
 <input type="hidden" id="ID" name="ID" value="<?php echo $ID ?>"/> 
 <input type="hidden" id="ReportPath" name="ReportPath" value="<?php echo $ReportPath ?>"/> 

 <input type="submit" id="remove" name="<?php echo $Report1?>" value="Remove"/>
</form>

<script>
$('#remove').click(function(){
    var id = $('#ID').val();
    var reportpath  = $('#ReportPath').val();
    var report1  = $('#Report1').val(); //check this as I dont see it in your form

    //call your function from here
    Remove(id, reportpath, report1);
});

//function definition here
function Remove(id, reportpath, report1)...
</script>
```

Comment: yes, somewhat like that. But where i put this 'var' stuff? In my document.ready function() ? or

Comment: How can i parse it on my button there ?

Comment: Kyokasuigetsu basically responded to your question. Now you can just call remove() function by `onlick="remove(); return false;"` and within the function set those 3 variables or pass data like so `onlick="remove(document.getElementById('ID').value, document.getElementById('ReportPath').value, document.getElementById('Report1').value); return false;"`. Did you consider using jQuery or other library for this?

Comment: javascript is enough for me :( Beginner learner. Still trying to adapt getting php with javascript.

Comment: @JLearner: that's good its actually better if you learn the fundamentals of javascript first before you use libraries like jquery for you to understand the basic concepts. Just google "javascript events" if you want to know the vanilla javascript equivalent of the codes I've written above. Good luck!

Comment: @Kyokasuigetsu, Alright. Javascript is my weakness. PHP is more on my strength. Cant seem to tune my logic from php to javascript or jquery. Thanks for your help! Really thanks for the previous posts that you have assist me! :)